# Adding advisor's name as a coparticipant without their permission

Tags: advisor, ethics, conference, professorship, conflict-of-interest

Thank you in advance. I had some issues with my advisor and want to get some advice. I got a Ph.D. degree from a foreign country and started my new postdoctoral position here in the US this year. Meanwhile, I participated in an imaging challenge where organizers provide a certain task that is considered important in our field and participants compete with one another to achieve the best results.

Since my approach was developed when I was in the previous laboratory, I wrote my previous laboratory as the institution and my previous professor as a coparticipant in the team information. There was, however, a policy that it isn't allowed to submit multiple results from the same research group, and there was another team in my previous lab. Thus, I changed the team institution from the previous one to my current institution and wrote my current advisor as my co-participant to avoid the multiple submission policy. My current advisor knew that I participated in the challenge but didn't know he was added as a coparticipant (it is definitely my mistake).

After several weeks, some top participants were posted on the conference website page, our team was there, and I told him the results. However, he took it very seriously and asked me to remove his name because he didn't contribute anything to my results. And he said that "You committed the fraudulent issue.". Of course, it is his right, so I sent an email to the challenge organizers and ask to remove his name from our team, and they answered positively. I was wrong about adding him without his agreement, but I feel a little bad. I'm not sure that it's really a fraudulent issue because it's neither publications nor conference presentations, and I added him since he is my current advisor. On the website, the team institution, members, and scores were only posted. Nothing else is included.

If I'm fully wrong about it, I may need to learn from the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you were wrong to add a non-participant and more so if you add someone without permission. It was an ethical breach.

You may have had good intentions, but that isn't a real excuse. Apologize, of course, and learn from the mistake. It isn't a career ender, after all.

The rules are similar to those of co-authorship here. Only contributors are listed and only with specific permission.